# Is it possible to set a variable based on the current route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

So, I have a sidenav component that looks like this:

```js
<MenuItems>
  <NavLink to="/contacts/new">New</NavLink>
  <NavLink to="/contacts/list">New (all)</NavLink>
  <NavLink to="/contacts/archived">Archived</NavLink>
  <NavLink to={`/contacts/responsible/${user?.id}`}>{user?.name}</NavLink>
</MenuItems>
```

And all these links redirect to my Home page, as you can see here:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path={[
      '/contacts/new',
      '/contacts/list',
      '/contacts/archived',
      '/contacts/responsible/:responsible',
      '/contacts/category/:category',
    ]}>
      <Home />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The thing is, in my `<Home />` page, I have a `<Contacts />` component that is the only component that should update whenever I access one of the routes above. Basically it should update a list calling a different api endpoint based on the current route. For example: if the current react route is `/contacts/archived`, the endpoint I need to call is `http://example.com/api/archivedContacts`.

For clarity, an example of what I am trying to do would be something like this:

```js
<Route path="/contacts/new" endpoint="/newContacts">
  <Home />
</Route>
<Route path="/contacts/archived" endpoint="/archivedContacts">
  <Home />
</Route>
<Route path="/contacts/category/:id" endpoint="/categoryContacts/:id">
  <Home />
</Route>
```

And then in my `<Contacts />` component that is inside `<Home />` I would like to do something like:

```js
export function Contacts() {
  // get the endpoint from the route or something like that
  const { pathname, endpoint } = useLocation();
  // useContacts is my context responsible to fetching and returning my contacts
  const { isLoading, fetchContacts, contacts } = useContacts();

  // refetch the contacts whenever the endpoint changes
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchContacts(endpoint);
  }, [endpoint, fetchContacts]);

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        {isLoading && (
          <Loading>
            <LoadingSpinner size={25} thickness={2} />
          </Loading>
        )}

        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Contact</th>
              <th>Last seen</th>
              <th>Responsible</th>
              <th>Category</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {// render contact list based on the route}
            {!isLoading && contacts.map((contact) => {
              {// list}
            })}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

export function Contacts() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pathname.includes('something')) {
      fetch('URL1')
    } else if (pathname.includes('anotherPath')) {
      fetch('URL2')
    }
  }, [pathname, fetchContacts]);
  
}
```